# Why with vue `pages` parameter in vue.config.js, localhost stops running?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In a 'standard' vue app, `yarn serve` (or `npm serve`) that refers to a serve script in package.json (`"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",`)
results in something like that:

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.4.86:8080/
```

When I define MPA in vue using `pages`

```js
const pages = {
    main: {
        entry: './src/main.js',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors']
    }
  }


module.exports = {

    runtimeCompiler: true,
  
    pages: pages,
    filenameHashing: false,
    productionSourceMap: false,
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? '/static/vue'
        : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    outputDir: '../_static/vue/',
    ...,
    config.devServer
            .public('http://localhost:8080')
            .host('localhost')
            .port(8080)
            .hotOnly(true)
            .watchOptions({ poll: 1000 })
            .https(false)
            .headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"] });
        config.module.rules.delete('eslint');

}
```

It stops working. How to make it work? (it is superhelpful for development)
UPDATE:
it returns an empty page with a title:

```
 <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

Comment: What mean stop working ? what you see in browser ? (request in network tab). Where is your configuration of devs server ? how it's look

Comment: just added dev server params

Comment: did you try http://localhost:8080/static/vue or http://localhost:8080/vue or http://localhost:8080/static or http://localhost:8080/_static etc.

Comment: What mean stop working ? is not displaying in browser or is not build

Comment: you have set chunks in entry. how looks your splitChunks configuration ? (you can remove chunks in entry for test)

Comment: I just removed `chunks` -  same thing. I actually removed all other devserver params, with the same result. Here is the vue.config.js file: https://gist.github.com/chapkovski/253014413f9a7c25a2a49ee7fc9911b7

Comment: I suspect that problme is in HTML plugin. Take a look on this [configuration](https://www.programmersought.com/article/3115500154/)